# Bash - Use of :- in Variables

Tags: bash, variables

I'm new to bash. When reading a bash script written by someone else I came across this line. I can't make the meaning of the operator used in it.

```
read -p "Enter user domain [subdomain.domain.org] : " USERDOMAIN
USERDOMAIN=${USERDOMAIN:-subdomain.domain.org]
```

I executed this in bash terminal and the value of USERDOMAIN remains the same as the value the user entered.

Can you explain what is being done at line 2?

Comment: 1) fix the typo 2) don't enter anything (that is, just press enter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I quote `man bash`:

```
${parameter:-word}
      Use Default Values. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion
      of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is
      substituted.
```

this in contrast:

```
${parameter:=word}
      Assign Default Values. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion
      of word is assigned to parameter. The value of parameter is then
      substituted.
```